# C#で作成したプログラム内部からVC++のDLLをWindows10だと呼び出せなくなる

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Windows7で作成したプログラムがWindows10では動作しなくなりました(Windows7では動作します)

C#からVC++(どちらも32bitでビルド)で作成されたDLLをDllImportで呼び出していたのですが
エラーを調べていたら
**DLL 'XXX.dll' を読み込めません:指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。 (HRESULT からの例外:0x8007007E)**
というエラーになりました

単純に

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "foofoo", CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static uint FooFoo();
```

として呼び出しているだけなのですが・・・・

C#のexeとVC++のdllは同じフォルダに配置しています

c#のVisual Studioは2013UPDATE5(.NETのターゲットバージョン4.5としてビルド)
VC++のVisual Studioは2008SP1

ランタイムが足りないのかと思い、Windows10にVC++2008SP1のランタイムも手動で入れてみたのですが同じエラーメッセージのままでした

エラーメッセージは単純にxxx.dllを見つけられないだけのようですが
他にはどのように原因が考えられるでしょうか

Comment: イベントログのアプリケーションログに不足しているDLLファイル名が記載されていませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++で作成されたDLLが、依存しているDLLがない場合にも同様のエラーとなります。
Dependency Walkerで必要なDLLを調べてみてください。
よくあるのがVCruntimeのいれ忘れ、x86x64のいれ間違いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。VCruntimeのバージョンが違ってました・・・恥ずかしい・・